# Is there an existing way to force or check that all values in an Immutable.js object are also immutable?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

We have run into cases in the past where someone accidently stores a mutable value inside of an Immutable.js object and then mutates the original object somehow. This causes unexpected side-effects and a false sense of security for those using the immutable object. Is there a way to force all mutations to be always be with immutable values or at least perform a deep check before performing a mutation?

These are two ways I was hoping you could accomplish what I am asking but neither work:

```
var test = Immutable.Map({foo: {bar: 'yeah'}}); // Only converts top level to an Immutable.Map

var test2 = fromJS(test); // Still the same as "test" (containing mutable objects)

Immutable.isImmutable(test); // true
Immutable.isImmutable(test2); // true
```